# iterating a filtered Numpy array whilst maintaining index information

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, loops

I am attempting to pass filtered values from a Numpy array into a function.
I need to pass values only above a certain value, and their index position  with the Numpy array.

I am attempting to avoid iterating over the entire array within python by using Numpys own filtering systems, the arrays i am dealing with have 20k of values in them with potentially only very few being relevant.

```
import numpy as np

somearray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
arrayindex = np.nonzero(somearray > 4)

for i in arrayindex:
    somefunction(arrayindex[0], somearray[arrayindex[0]])
```

This threw up errors of logic not being able to handle multiple values,
this led me to testing it through print statement to see what was going on.

```
for cell in arrayindex:
    print(f"index {cell}")
    print(f"data {somearray[cell]}")
```

I expected an output of

```
index 4
data 5
index 5
data 6
```

But instead i get

```
index [4 5]
data [5 6]
```

I have looked through different methods to iterate through numpy arrays such and neditor, but none seem to still allow me to do the filtering of values outside of the for loop.

Is there a solution to my quandary?

Oh, i am aware that is is generally frowned upon to loop through a numpy array, however the function that i am passing these values to are complex, triggering certain events and involving data to be uploaded to a data base dependent on the data location within the array.

Thanks.

Comment: _This threw up errors_ Always share the entire error message. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
somearray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
arrayindex = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(somearray) if val > 4]

for i in range(0, len(arrayindex)):
    somefunction(arrayindex[i], somearray[arrayindex[i]])

for i in range(0, len(arrayindex)):
    print("index", arrayindex[i])
    print("data", somearray[arrayindex[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a clear idea of what `nonzero` produces, and pay attention to the difference between indexing with a list(s) and with a tuple.

===

```
In [110]: somearray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) 
     ...: arrayindex = np.nonzero(somearray > 4)
```

`nonzero` produces a tuple of arrays, one per dimension (this becomes more obvious with 2d arrays):

```
In [111]: arrayindex                                                                           
Out[111]: (array([4, 5]),)
```

It can be used directly as an index:

```
In [113]: somearray[arrayindex]                                                                
Out[113]: array([5, 6])
```

In this 1d case you could take the array out of the tuple, and iterate on it:

```
In [114]: for i in arrayindex[0]:print(i, somearray[i])                                        
4 5
5 6
```

`argwhere` does a 'transpose', which could also be used for iteration

```
In [115]: idxs = np.argwhere(somearray>4)                                                      
In [116]: idxs                                                                                 
Out[116]: 
array([[4],
       [5]])
In [117]: for i in idxs: print(i,somearray[i])                                                 
[4] [5]
[5] [6]
```

`idxs` is (2,1) shape, so `i` is (1,) shape array, resulting in the brackets in the display.  Occasionally it's useful, but `nonzero` is used more (often by it's other name, `np.where`).

## 2d

`argwhere` has a 2d example:

```
In [119]: x=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                                                          
In [120]: np.argwhere(x>1)                                                                     
Out[120]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
In [121]: np.nonzero(x>1)                                                                      
Out[121]: (array([0, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))
In [122]: x[np.nonzero(x>1)]                                                                   
Out[122]: array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

While `nonzero` can be used to index the array, `argwhere` elements can't.

```
In [123]: for ij in np.argwhere(x>1): 
     ...:     print(ij,x[ij]) 
     ...:                                                                                      
...
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Problem is that `ij` is a list, which is used to index on dimension.  `numpy` distinguishes between lists and tuples when indexing.  (Earlier versions fudged the difference, but current versions are taking a more rigorous approach.)

So we need to change the list into a tuple.  One way is to unpack it:

```
In [124]: for i,j in np.argwhere(x>1): 
     ...:     print(i,j,x[i,j]) 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                      
0 2 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
1 2 5
```

I could have used: `print(ij,x[tuple(ij)])` in [123].

I should have used unpacking the [117] iteration:

```
In [125]: for i, in idxs: print(i,somearray[i])                                                
4 5
5 6
```

or `somearray[tuple(i)]`